# Can I get hg log to print the history in reverse order?

Tags: git, mercurial, history, logging, reverse

If not, is this a feature that git has?

Comment: It already does print in reverse, you need reverse-reverse (or forward). Hence some of the answers give the normal order (reversed).

Comment: It there a way to get it to work with `-G` (graph)? I was using `hg log | tac` but the `/`s and `\`s come out the wrong way (and there is no colour). I only need it for use with `-G`

Answer (score 43, accepted):

[YGL's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795994/can-i-get-hg-log-to-print-the-history-in-reverse-order/2796024#2796024) is the right one for log, see [this thread](http://old.nabble.com/Show-log-in-reverse-order-td28158687.html):

> The hint from "hg help log" might be:
> "If no revision range is specified, the default is tip:0". Combine this with the knowlegde from "[hg help multirevs](http://bitbucket.org/mirror/mercurial/src/47fbbc4845ff/mercurial/help/multirevs.txt)". That is:

**`hg log -r :`**

**multirevs**:

> When Mercurial accepts more than one revision, they may be specified individually, or provided as a topologically continuous range, separated by the "`:`" character.
>
> The syntax of range notation is **`[BEGIN]:[END]`**, where `BEGIN` and `END` are revision identifiers.
> Both `BEGIN` and `END` are optional.
> If `BEGIN` is not specified, it defaults to revision number 0.
> If `END` is not specified, it defaults to the tip.
> The range ":" thus means "all revisions".

If `BEGIN` is greater than `END`, revisions are treated in reverse order.

> A range acts as a closed interval. This means that a range of `3:5` gives 3, 4 and 5.
> Similarly, a range of `9:6` gives 9, 8, 7, and 6.

---

Note: if you want to do the same with **[Graphlog](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/GraphlogExtension)** (the `glog` that behaves like (a subset of) the normal `log` command except that it also prints a graph representing the revision history using ASCII characters to the left of the `log`.), you will need [a patch](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/pipermail/mercurial-devel/2010-April/020064.html).

> I should warn you that it will be *very* slow for large graphs, particularly `0:tip`.
> See [patch 1](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/pipermail/mercurial-devel/2010-April/020075.html) and [patch 2](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/pipermail/mercurial-devel/2010-April/020076.html). I am working on improving that.

Answer (score 24):

Did you try

`hg log -r :`

Answer (score 11):

If you'd like to set reverse-order as a default, add this line to your hgrc (<repo>/.hg/hgrc, $HOME/.hgrc, /etc/mercurial/hgrc):

```
[defaults]
log = -r :
```

Comment: I'm assuming that this changes the default behavior of hg log to show the history in reverse order.

Comment: I initially upvoted this, but now I realize that this won't work for me as it breaks the ability for hg log to show a single revision.  That is, hg log now shows revisions in reverse.  Good. However, hg log -r 25 won't show just changeset 25 - it will still show the entire list of changesets.

Answer (score 7):

An alternative to nad2000's answer would be to simply add an alias in `~/.hgrc`

```
[alias]
logr = log -r :
```

Now calling `hg logr` displays the logs in reverse order. Unfortunately, as pointed out by VonC, the same type of alias cannot be defined for `glog`, since `hg glog -r :` does not display the logs in reverse order.

Comment: +1 Adding an alias seems like a better idea than changing the default behavior. (@firebush explains why)

Answer (score 7):

Just in order to mention

Revset (long) version:

`hg log -r "sort(all(),-date)"`

Comment: This is really the correct answer. 'log -r :' doesn't work if you need a DAG log (::) instead of a chronological log (:).

Answer (score 7):

I'm surprised nobody mentioned reverse() yet. Maybe it's a newer hg feature?

`hg log -r "reverse(all())"`

Sure, you could go with tip:0 as well. I like reverse because I also often use it when mixed with ancestors.

`hg log -r "reverse(::12345)"`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this has since changed or I’ve done something wrong, but I get reverse-chronological order logs from Mercurial like this:

```
hg log -r tip:0
```

I usually limit them to the most recent log entries too, using `-l`:

```
hg log -r tip:0 -l 3
```